# Using python-oauth2 I get oauth_parameters_absent:scope

Tags: python, oauth

Try to use python-auth2 for my project, but I got:

```
In [1]: import oauth2 as oauth

In [2]: consumer_key='dijscrape.ep.io'

In [3]: consumer_secret='my-secret-here'

In [4]: REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken'

In [5]: consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

In [6]: client = oauth.Client(consumer)

In [7]: r, c = client.request(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, "GET")

In [8]: print r
------> print(r)
{'status': '400', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'expires': 'Tue, 26 Jul 2011 13:38:13 GMT', 'server': 'GSE', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Tue, 26 Jul 2011 13:38:13 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'}

In [9]: print c
------> print(c)
parameter_absent
oauth_parameters_absent:scope
```

What it can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google requires a 'scope' parameter for the request_token uri.

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html#prepScope

So something like

```
scope = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full"
REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope={0}'.format(scope)
```

I notice you haven't accepted an answer to any of the questions you've asked. If an answer helps, please remember to accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.